# Installing mysql 5.1 in CentOS7

Tags: mysql, centos7

I am using CentOS7 and currently I have installed mysql 5.7 in my machine. I want to install mysql 5.1 for a testing purpose. For the whole day I couldn't find out a way to do that. Please help me this case.
* I need to know that am I in a IMPOSSIBLE task ?
* If it is possible, how (any source) ?

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat ships with MariaDB 5.5. If your are want older version you can try:

1) build from source by your self. But it's can be difficalt

2) Use docker container. Just run new instance and link it to your app. (like this: [mysql docker github](https://github.com/vsamov/mysql-5.1.73))

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the RPMs in the Download archive (https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/) or download the source package and follow the instructions in the INSTALL file.